# CSS Two Boxes with same height

Tags: css, wordpress

All I want is to make right column's height (and images in it) depend on the left. Left one's height keeps changing based on width and right column's height changes too but they are never equal.

CSS

```
div.home-bottomleft, div.home-bottomright {
    float:left;
    display:table-row;
    padding:10px 0;
}
div.home-bottomleft {
    width:45.3%;
    background: url(/wp-content/themes/jdesign/images/div-separator.png) right no-repeat;
}
div.home-bottomright {
    width:54.7%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="home-bottomleft">
<img class="home-bottom-motive" src="/wp-content/themes/jdesign/images/homepage-motive.png" alt="Bottom Top Motive" /></p>
<p class="book_antiqua home-bottomtext">XX Events is a full-service event planning company in Chicago dedicated to creating an enjoyable and stress-free planning experience for our clients. We are motivated by event trends, inspired by traditions, and fascinated by all of the details that go into a personalized and flawless event!</p>
</div>
<div class="home-bottomright">
<div class="home-brbox"><img class="home-brbox-img" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/XXevents-bottomleftimg.jpg" alt="XXevents" /></p>
<p>Weddings</p>
</div>
<div class="home-brbox"><img class="home-brbox-img" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/XXevents-bottommiddleimg.jpg" alt="XXevents" /></p>
<p>Social Events</p>
</div>
<div class="home-brbox"><img class="home-brbox-img" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/XXevents-bottomrightimg.jpg" alt="XXevents" /></p>
<p>Showers</p>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Left one's height keeps changing based on width and right column's height changes too but they are never equal So what is 45.3% and 54.7% for right and left

Comment: What do u want to be equal ?

Comment: 45.3 and 54.7 is so the separator in the between corresponds the specific part of the page and looks organized

Comment: I want left side last line's to be lined up with right side's last line's text.

Comment: It's fluid design. I want both sides to get bigger/smaller together not on their own. Images go overboard

Comment: is this web alive ? mean public ?

Comment: This is part of a WordPress theme? Which means the HTML is probably not open to any change otherwise the layout will break.

Comment: You are asking for some tricky stuff here.  In your top example, the text is large, so the images may be scaled to fit the height of the parent container, but that would also mean that the width would increase, which could force the images to start another line if they are floated.  In your second example with smaller text, you could shrink the images or make the line-height in the left area larger (in some flexible manner, but that could lead to readability problems.  How about vertically centering the text block on the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have a left column with varied height, and you want the right column's height to be determined by the left (I think - your question is not entirely clear).

The easiest way to do this is to have the left element in flow, and the right element absolutely positioned and stretched to its container.

You can see this effect at: http://jsfiddle.net/yNKxG/1/

A pseduo-HTML example:

```
<container>
    <div, width: 50%;></div>
    <div, position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 50%;></div>
</container>
```

Note that this won't include the text resizing you show in your mockup; that will have to be achieved through some other means (possibly only JavaScript, unless the change in the height of the left column is triggered through media query breakpoints).

Comment: I don't know how to apply this to my case though.

Answer (score 2):

In the parent element add `display:table` to your CSS; then on your CSS Columns add `display:table-cell`.